# How to show different content for various roles for the same url?

Tags: nodes

we have a use case whereby 6-7 types of user roles can access the same nodes (lots of them) and see different content based on roles.

For example a user with role A accesses sitename.com/faq and sees a particular content. 
However when a user with role B accesses sitename/faq that they see some different content as based on their role. (Please note that we are not merely talking about translation here)

How would I get about getting this setup? I know that if we had 2-3 nodes that required such access that I could check it programmatically however in this case it is a lot of nodes and doing that would be problematic.

Any tips or modules that you can think off that would help me with that?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using page manager with variants set on role based contexts. Assuming you've got chaos tool suite installed, you already have it.

If you haven't made use of page manager, it is accessed from /admin/structure/pages

A decent introduction to the sort of thing you want to do can be found here:
http://nodeone.se/en/learn-page-manager-part-1-overview

At its simplest, page manager can be used to override default paths using a redirect, based on context settings, like ... say ... the roles of the currently logged in user. It integrates well with panels, providing context for panels based content, including views content panes.

Using the Context module might work for you too, depending on how you've set up your pages. I use that one for placing blocks based on user roles and paths. https://drupal.org/project/context  ... um ... "block system on steroids" is one description of it.

Without knowing a bit more about how you've set up your FAQs, that's about all I can give you for now.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like either the [Content Access](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) module, the [ACL](https://drupal.org/project/acl) module, (maybe) the [Nodeaccess](https://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module, or possibly even a combination thereof, would be a good place to start.